# How show a primefaces chart in a modal?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, charts, size

I generate a image with javascript and show the result in a modal, but the image leaves of the modal: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9603018modal.png

This is my code:

XHTML

```
<h:form id = "form1">
    <p:chart widgetVar="chart" style="width:1200px;height:400px" type = "bar" model="#{graphicBean.barModel}" rendered="#{not empty graphicBean.barModel}"/>
    <p:commandButton onclick ="exportChart()" value = "Execute"/>
    <b:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" value="Show" ajax="true" oncomplete="$('.modalGraphic').modal();return false;" />
</h:form>

<b:modal id="id_modalGraphic" styleClass="modalGraphic" title="Guarda el gráfico">
     <h:form id = "resultado">
         <h:panelGroup id="output" layout="block" style="width:100px;height:100px"></h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</b:modal>
```

JavaScript

```
function exportChart() {
  $('#resultado\\:output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());
}
```

I would like a short picture or a original size picture with a scroll.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the modal has some overflow css to show things instead of scroll? Is the image in the right place in the modal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way:

```
<p:commandButton value="Modal" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" />

<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">

    here goes what you want to show in the modal

</p:dialog>
```

this is using primefaces

Comment: uhmmm that is what the OP is doing. The outputPanel is in the dialog. And OP wants to attach the image from the chart to it (the exported image), that is what the jQuery part is doing..